# Is this a insecure way to use prepared statements in a php class?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I made this Class with the function query():

This function makes it really easy to use prepared statements.
But

- It is secure?
- Make it even sense to use it like that?

I already tested it with [sqlmap](https://sqlmap.org) and it looks good.

The function basicly split the normal SELECT string into multiple smaller string to dedect the input values.
It save the input values and the string itself.
The string itself will be replaced by ?.
Than the normal prepare function replaces the ? again with the input values.

```
    class dbcon
    {   
        public $con;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->con = new mysqli( $host, $username, $password, $dbname );
        }


    public function query( $query )
    {   
        //selcet
        if( strpos( $query, "SELECT" ) !== false )
        {   
            $types = ""; $to_replace = []; $values = [];

            $query = explode( "WHERE", $query );
            $query_where = explode( "ORDER BY", $query[ '1' ] );

            $query_where[ '0' ];

            if( isset( $query_where[ '1' ] ) ) 
            { 
                $ORDERBY = explode("LIMIT", $query_where[ '1' ]); 
            }
            if( isset( $ORDERBY[ '1' ] ) )
            {
                $LIMIT = $ORDERBY[ '1' ];
            }

            $SELECT = $query[ '0' ];

            $where = str_replace( array( "(", ")", "[", "]" ), "", $query_where[ '0' ] );
            $where = str_replace( array( "AND", "OR", "and", "or" ), "-|-", $where );
            $where = explode( "-|-", $where );

            for ($i=0; $i < count($where); $i++) {
                $for_where = str_replace( array( "!=", "<=", ">=", "=", "<>", ">", "<", "IS", "NOT LIKE", "LIKE" ), "#|#", $where[ $i ] );
                $for_where = explode( "#|#", $for_where );

                $value = trim( $for_where[ '1' ] );
                if( substr_count($value, "AND") <= 0 AND substr_count($value, "OR") <= 0 )
                {
                    $value = "'?'";
                }

                $to_replace[] = $value;
                $value_num = "values".$i;
                $$value_num = $value;
                $values[] = &$$value_num;

                $types .= "s";
            }
            $WHERE = str_replace( $to_replace , " ? ", $query_where[ '0' ] );

            $prepare = $SELECT . " WHERE " . $WHERE;
            if ( isset( $ORDERBY ) )
            {
                $prepare .= " ORDER BY " . $ORDERBY[ '0' ];
            }
            if ( isset( $LIMIT ) ){
                $prepare .= " LIMIT " . $LIMIT;
            }

            $stmt = $this->con->prepare( $prepare );
            //$stmt->bind_param($types, $values['0'],$values['1']);
            call_user_func_array( array( $stmt, "bind_param" ), array_merge( array( $types ), $values ) );

            $stmt->execute();
                return $stmt->get_result();
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
}

$db = new dbcon();
```

Call the function:

```
$id = $_GET[ 'id' ];
$my_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = '$id' ORDER BY created DESC");

while($row = $my_query->fetch_array()){ 
    echo $row['NAME']."<br>";   
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The old function makes not a lot of sense and is not secure at all. This should be still a easy way but better.

```
public function query( $query, $types, $query_values )
{   
    $values = [];


for ($i=0; $i < count($query_values); $i++) {
    $value_num = "values".$i;
    $$value_num = $query_values[ $i ];
    $values[] = &$$value_num;
}

$stmt = $this->con->prepare( $query );
call_user_func_array( array( $stmt, "bind_param" ), array_merge( array( $types ), $values ) );

$stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

call the function

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM _Users WHERE ID = ? ORDER BY created ASC";
$my_query = $db->query( $query, "s", array( $id ) );

while($row = $my_query->fetch_array()){
    echo $row['title']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Which question do you want us to answer; the one in the title, or the one in the body?

Comment: Just... why do this at all? Why not have a query method that accepts a paramerterised query, and an array of things to bind?

Comment: This belongs to Code Review site.

Comment: @SilvanFux `Make it even sense to use it like that?` - No.

Comment: @strawberry Is it not that the same?

Comment: [How much easier do prepared statements need to be made…?!](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/57248909/i-cant-even.jpg) `$pdo->prepare($query)->execute($params)`

Comment: Well, the answer to one is 'yes', and the other is 'no'.

Comment: It should be a **new** question, not an update. Better be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com as on SO such question is rather off topic.

Comment: this is the most complicated bit of code to achieve nothing that I have ever seen

Comment: @jameson2012 is even worse than that. It makes sql injection a lot easier than it already is, without prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot by definition "prepare"/"sanitise"/*understand* a query after you have already interpolated values into it.

> ```
> $my_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = '$id' ORDER BY created DESC");
> ```

So what happens here if someone attempts some SQL injection? E.g.: `$id = "foo' OR '1' = '1"`:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = 'foo' OR '1' = '1' ORDER BY created DESC
```

How could any code *following* this possibly understand the difference between what this query was *supposed* to do and what it is *actually* doing now? It cannot. The meaning has already been altered through value injection. There's no way to fix this after the fact.

Comment: Yea I see the problem.

Comment: Updated the function completely. The new one should be secure.